# How to get speed and acceleration from trajectory data?

Tags: java, gps

I am using Java to develop a project. I have got some trajectory data by applying a spatial query. My question is, how can I get speed and acceleration for these trajectory data? Does java has useful library to do so?
for more information: points has (x,y,z,t)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

no java has not.

speed is distance per time.
to calculate distance you can use the haversine formula, asuming x,y are in latitude longitude. z is ignored.
Depending on the plattform (e.g Android) there is a lib for that,
otherwise search for haversine distance.

Comment: thanks for your replay. to do so I googled and saw "kalman" filter. do you have any tutorial for that?

Comment: forget that, you dont need that, the gps locations are already heavily kalman filtered from the gps chip. Unfortunetly you dont have a speed attribute, therefore you would need some filtering in some critical situations. (jumping locations)

Comment: you means only if I had speed attribute I could use kalman filter?

Comment: no, if you have speed, you could ignore low speed locations, which cause jumping locations, depending on the settings of the gps chip

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time. My last question is: can I use "cubic spiline" to determine speed and acceleration? if so, do you have any tutorial for that?

Comment: you could, but I doubt there is an  improvement to linear approiach. there are many spline types, some create artficial bows.  Your main task will be to filter out "untypical " situations